Can I use tsParticles with Tauri?
I'm trying to incorporate tsParticles with my Tauri app, but I'm encountering some issues.
Initially, I received the following error:
InteractionManager.js:31  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: interactor.init is not a function
at InteractionManager.init (InteractionManager.js:31:24)
at Particles.init (Particles.js:155:34)
at Container.init (Container.js:301:24)
at async Container.start (Container.js:404:9)
at async Engine._loadParams (Engine.js:278:9)
at async _Particles.loadParticles (Particles.js:75:89)
at async _Particles.<anonymous> (Particles.js:51:17)

To fix this, I changed my import from loadFull to loadSlim:
import { loadSlim } from 'tsparticles-slim'

const init = useCallback(async (engine: any) => {
    await loadSlim(engine)
}, [])

However, this resulted in a new error:
react-dom.development.js:26962  Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at deepCompare (Utils.js:2:17)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)
at deepCompare (Utils.js:16:18)

I also tried downgrading React to v17, but this caused more issues with Tauri and didn't seem to help.
Here's the entire function for reference:
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import Particles from 'react-tsparticles'
import { loadFull } from 'tsparticles'

function MyParticles() 
{
    const init = useCallback(async (engine: any) => {
        await loadFull(engine)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Particles
            id="tsparticles"
            init={init}
            options={/* removed for simplicity but it's just a preset from tsParticles demo website */}
        />
    )
}

export default MyParticles

And here's how I'm using the MyParticles component:
import MyParticles from './particles'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyParticles/>
    </>
  ) 
}

I'm not sure how to get tsParticles to render properly in this context. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Seems like

Removing the id field (im not sure if this did anything but im too tired to check)
Using loadSlim from tsparticles-slim (not @tsparticles/slim)
Downgrading to the following:
react@18.2.0
react-tsparticles@2.12.2
tsparticles@3.3.0

